# Cause for CS0542 - "member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type"

Tags: c#, .net

I Have this error but i can't identify the error (CS0542) for some reason:

> member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type

Code:

```
class SuperTeam
{
    string SuperTeamName;

    public SuperTeam()
    {
        SuperTeamName = "";
    }

    public void SuperTeam (string nSuperTeamName)
    {
        SuperTeamName = nSuperTeamName;
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand correct first and fast second that's what I did :(

Comment: that's true but it was edited 1 minute ago

Comment: @JulieShannon, I just added some extra details pointed out by Alexei, before that it was fine too :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the link please :)

Comment: @JulieShannon
Sorry if i did something wrong unintentionally , I am new here and generally in programming but i found Matt's answer more comprehensive for me . :)

Comment: @AngeloB., Its totally up to you to mark any answer as acceptable or not to mark at all, You earlier marked Matt's answer as the correct one and now you marked mine. If you think Matt's answer is the correct one then accept that, don't worry about the number of votes or any comments. Its your choice :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
public void SuperTeam(string nSuperTeamName)
{
    SuperTeamName = nSuperTeamName;
}
```

I believe you wanted to have a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx) for your class, and since constructor can't have a return type, the compiler is treating it as a method. Now the method name is same as the class name, that is why you are getting the error.

- If it is a constructor then remove `void` (return type)
- If it is a simple method then change the name to something other than `SuperTeam`

See [Details about your Error - Compiler Error CS0542:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdhfk2xk%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> The members of a class or struct cannot have the same name as the
>   class or struct, **unless the member is a constructor**

AND *(thanks to [@Alexei Levenkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477420/alexei-levenkov))*

> This error might be caused if you **inadvertently put a return type on
>   a constructor**, which in effect makes it into an ordinary method.

Comment: +1. Note that article for CS0542 explicitly covers this case: "This error might be caused if you inadvertently put a return type on a constructor, which in effect makes it into an ordinary method..."

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, perfect addition, just added that to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

you have conflict the method has some name as the class constructor
try this for example

```
public SuperTeam()
{
    SuperTeamName = "";
}

public void SuperTeamMethod (string nSuperTeamName)
{
    SuperTeamName = nSuperTeamName;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your class is SuperTeam and it has a method called SuperTeam that isn't a constructor. I'm guessing that it was supposed to be a constructor, in which case, drop the `void` return type

```
public SuperTeam (string nSuperTeamName)
{
    SuperTeamName = nSuperTeamName;
}
```

If it's actually supposed to be a method for setting `SuperTeamName` then change the name of the function (`SetSuperTeamName` would seem appropriate), or better yet change it into a property with a getter and a setter.

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor with the string `nSuperTeamName` is not supposed to have `void`. By having `void`, you made it one of the class' members.